# Using the autohotencoder in PySpark for a linear regression but no reference category

Tags: regression-coefficients, categorical-encoding

I created dummy variables using the autohotencoder and as I have learned dummy variables you also need to have a reference category. However I have 7 dummy variables for the weekdays for example, so I have no reference category. How do I go about interpreting the coefficients without this reference category?

Comment: You can use one day of the week - say Monday - as a reference/baseline.

Comment: This will depend on what parameterization of categorical variables autohotencoder uses. That should be in the documentation. You might also be able to change it.